# getting files in from previous commits with git when merging. efficiency

Tags: git

I merge to main, and I'm not satisfied. For instance foo.c is not the version I want, and I want a version from commit "blah" on branch "bar". What I do now is checkout "blah" on branch "bar" copy everything in file foo.c in a text editor, checkout main again, open the version of foo.c I didn't like, and then clobber it by pasting in what I've copying.

There's got to be a better way.

Any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 git checkout bar path/to/foo.c
```

should do it. However, if you would like to see what foo.c contains you can use `git show`:

```
 git show <some sha1 or other reference>:path/to/foo.c
```

so to see what the file contained 2 commits ago, you can:

```
 git show HEAD^^:path/to/foo.c
```

current commit's copy can be shortened to:

```
 git show :path/to/foo.c
```

Answer (score 2):

`git checkout bar -- foo.c`  will check out only the file `foo.c` from the branch `bar` without touching other files in your working tree.

This is covered in [the documentation for `git checkout`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-checkout.html).

Comment: you only need the "--" if there's some ambiguity, ordinarily `git checkout branch fileOrPath` is sufficient.

Comment: great. the term "if there's some ambiguity" is ambiguous to me now. what's an example of there being some ambiguity?

Comment: Having a branch with the same name as a fileOrFolder. `git checkout --help` has more details

Comment: @DavidWest, also note that sometimes you just want `git checkout --ours $file` or `git checkout --theirs $file` to just get the contents of the file as held by either side of the merge just performed.